# Scrollable link list HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am in the need of adding some more functionality to a couple of list items inside an `ul`, and I would like to know how I can use scroll functions to be able to scroll up and down because of the amount of items.

This is my list:

```
<ul>
<li>Page 1</li>
<li>Page 2</li>
<li>Page 3</li>
<li>Page 4</li>
<li>Page 5</li>
<li>Page 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

Im not exactly sure if this is what you're searching for, but you can wrap the list with a element which has a defined height.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Page 4</li>
    <li>Page 5</li>
    <li>Page 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...and the css:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:auto;
    height:200px;
}
```

So if the list is longer/higher than 200px (or what ever you've specified) a vertical scrollbar will show up.

Comment: for a cleaner look you might consider `overflow-y:auto;` and set a width in your `#wrapper` tag wide enough to accomodate the list. That way you only have a vertical scrollbar, not a horizontal.

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt quite do it. Once you scroll, both 2nd and 3rd items appear at the same time.

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @DinoExcel I think I understood your question wrong. What do you want to accomplish? Could you please give me a detailed description.